It is related to hijab
I study in a Christian missionary school. In my school hijab is not allowed, I tried talking to my Principal and she straight away refused me. This is my last year of school so I cannot leave my school.
I have the intention of wearing hijab but I cannot wear in school, will I be sinful for this? And if somehow my photos in school uniform are uploaded somewhere without my knowledge will I be sinful for that?

You can change your school, people do it all the time. Hijab is obligatory and if you are unable to practice your religion you are obligated to migrate to a place where you can practice it.

Also see Am I still obligated to wear hijab at school when the school forbids it?
